# Printing character occurrence in string - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to count how many times each character appears in a string but have a couple problems with the program printing out different counts for upper/lower case as well as it **not** printing out a count of 0 for characters that dont show up.

The desired output should be something along the lines of...

> A = 0
>
> B = 1
>
> C = 2
>
> ...
>
> X = 0
>
> Y = 1
>
> Z = 2

as well as listing the number of times 0-9 occurs or if it doesn't occur. I have figured out a working way to prevent characters that are upper/lower case not being counted together (p = 1, P = 1) but am not sure if it is the most efficient. The main problem though is getting the program to print characters that don't appear in the string. Most of the other posts I've come across deal with the user checking to see how many times a certain character appears rather than all characters.

The code I have so far is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LetterCount  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String myInput;

    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("input_test"));
    myInput = fileIn.nextLine();

    myInput=charAdjust(myInput);
    charCounter(myInput);
    fileIn.close();

}

public static String charAdjust(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String str;
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("input_test"));
    str=fileIn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("-----------");
    fileIn.close();
    return (str.toUpperCase());

}
public static String charCounter(String str) {
    int[]counter = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char charAt = str.charAt(i);
        counter[(int) charAt]++;
    }

        for (int i=0; i<counter.length; i++) {
            if (counter[i] > 0)
                System.out.println((char)i + " = " + counter[i]);

        }
        return str;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you looking only for some specific characters? Otherwise, the majority of 65536 character positions would print zeros.

Comment: If it's only a-z you can use an array of 26 and subtract 'a' or 'A' from str.charAt(i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips:

---

Don't worry too much about further efficiency for now -- you're doing the right thing by only looping through the characters in the string once. Some beginners would have read through the string once for each char they're searching for, making it really slow, and you've avoided that.

There are some other techniques for iterating through a string, e.g. `StringReader`, but you'll encounter them soon enough, and `charAt()` is fine for now. (Indeed, `String.charAt()` is super-fast -- under the covers it's a cheap array lookup. Other options will be about the same speed, but potentially more expressive, and more adaptable to other sources of characters, such as files or network streams).

You can't avoid having two loops: once through the input string to collect your counts, then another through the `counter` array to output the result.

---

Your strategy of using `toUpperCase` first is OK, and common. For really long inputs, it might be better to uppercase each char as you encounter it:

```
  char charAt = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i));
```

This is because behind the scenes, `String.toUpperCase()` is (of course) looping through the input string, so you're adding a third loop, where two is enough. If you know the input isn't huge, though, this really doesn't matter.

---

Since you're only interested in A-Z and 0-9 you can use a `counter` array of size 36 -- or 37 if you reserve one slot for 'other'. You'll need to write a method to convert a char to its index:

```
  int charToIndex(char c) {
       char upper = Character.toUpperCase(c);
       if(upper >= 'A' && upper <= 'Z') {
           // returns 1 for 'A' ... 26 for 'Z'
           return (upper - 'A') + 1;
       }
       if(upper >= '0' && upper <= '9') {
           // returns 27 for '0' ... 37 for '9'
           return 27 + (upper - '0');
       }
       return 0; // meaning 'other'
  }
```

Now to output your counts, you just need to loop through this small array, outputting every item. You'll need to write another method to convert an index back to a printable letter/number.

---

Note this only works for the ASCII letters and numbers. Things get more complicated in the world of Unicode, in which there are hundreds of other characters, including emoticons, non-roman alphabets, and even symbols that look exactly like letters from the latin alphabet, but have different codes.

Comment: Good answer. But the only thing I don't like is where you say "Don't worry too much about efficiency". Objectively, I get it - Java intentionally abstracts all the micromanaging away, but it's a dangerous path to go down where you ignore efficiency in the beginning and then towards the end, you have a program that you are forced to write in Java by your manager, and requirements that dictate time and now you don't know how to write a fast Java application. A common thing that is said is 'if it needs to be fast, don't write it in Java' but we don't always have that level of control.

Comment: Modified to "further efficiency". It's already `O(x)` which is as good as can be. You could go nuts trying to minimise `x`: for operations on strings it's generally a waste of effort as `x` is already tiny -- and OP is clearly a beginner. (see also: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/ )

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way of doing this. Strictly speaking, in order to determine the count for all the letters of the alphabet, you have to know what the alphabet is.

For example, you're clearly an English speaking person, so it would be `[A-Za-z0-9]` based on the rules you defined in your post. But imagine you are Russian; your alphabet would change and your program would need to function differently. The only way for you to know what those letters are, is to define them.

If you are talking about just English, and just `[A-Za-z0-9]` then it gets a little simpler. `[A-Za-z0-9]` are represented in ASCII, and can be represented as numerical values, which from your code snippet, you clearly already know.

The way you are attempting this from your code snippet is about the most efficient way you can go - with a caveat or two. If you know C in any way, shape, or form, then you know what I'm about to explain, but to be complete, I will describe it anyway. Basically, you are saying that you have a section of memory starting at a memory address N. The address is the size of a character (which should be 2 bytes in Java, rather than 1 byte in C - although this is abstracted away in Java and is not strictly 2 bytes, it just usually is to my knowledge) multiplied by the number of indices of the array (in your case, it's 2^16, or 65536 indices). When you say `array[N]`, under the hood it's smart enough to know to jump exactly to the memory address of N*size_of_char and get the value at that address. This is as quick as it gets.

The part of your logic where you fall a little behind, is that your buffer, as hinted at in the previous section, is 65536 indices large, which is clearly more than you care about based on the requirements you've described. This can be mitigated, however, using some simple logic to only read the indices you care about when you're trying to handle your metrics. In other words, only read from the indices at `48-57` (0-9), `65-90` (A-Z), and `97-122` (a-z).

The next best thing is to use a Java Collection, such as a `HashMap`. This is far less efficient than the array you're using though, so I wouldn't recommend it.

EDIT: I wasn't clear on whether or not you were trying to aggregate the count of characters for `a-z` and `A-Z` together, or if you were trying to count them separately. It is not difficult to do them together or separate. As somebody mentioned in a comment to you question, you can use arithmetic to get upper/lowercase letters from ASCII characters which is pretty quick (and by pretty quick, I mean that's a single CPU cycle).

EDIT 2: On reviewing, it appears I didn't necessarily answer all of your question. To print out the characters that don't appear in the String, you would simply read from your array from indicies `48-57` (0-9), `65-90` (A-Z), and `97-122` (a-z) and print out the values. When you initialize an array, it initializes to nulled out values. In your case, you use an `int` array. `int` is a primitive, and a primitive's version of a nulled out value translates to a zero value. For `int`, `short`, `byte`, and `char` that means 0, for `boolean` that means false, for `long` that means 0L, and for `double` and `float` that means 0F. In other words, you don't have to do anything explicit to get the characters that don't appear in your String. Just read all the indices that relate to letters that you care about and it will give you a 'nulled' (or zero) value if it was not part of your String.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* Most common string occurrence related solutions using java 8 */
    
    //find all character occurrences in a string
    String myString = "test";
    List<Character> list = myString.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.stream().distinct().forEach(c -> System.out.println(c + " = " + Collections.frequency(list, c)));

    //find one specific character occurrence in a string
    String myString = "test";
    char search = 't';
    long count = myString.chars().filter(c -> c == search).count();
    System.out.println(count);

    //find all unique characters in a string
    String myString = "test";
    List<Character> list = myString.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.stream().filter(c -> Collections.frequency(list,c) == 1).forEach(System.out::println);

    //find first unique character in a string
    String myString = "test";
    List<Character> list = myString.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    char firstUniqueChar = list.stream().filter(c -> Collections.frequency(list,c) == 1).findFirst().get();
    System.out.println(firstUniqueChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an int array with capacity for 123 elements (from `'0'` to `'9'` and `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'a'` to `'z'`, the highest value is `'z'`, which is 122).

Iterate each character and use it as the index in the counter. Do **NOT** uppercase anything - that is a waste of time.

When printing the letters, you only need to go from index 65 to 90 (those are the uppercase letters). Did you know that the separation between an uppercase and its lowercase counterpart is 32? In other words, you can put both `'a'` and `'A'` together by doing something like `counter['A'] + counter['A' + 32]`. No need to uppercase anything.

When printing the numbers, you only need to go from index 48 to 57.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input            = "sjdSaaASDB12bbBBB555BbbbjsdajdasJDa51hkajsdJASDHKjasd2233haksjdDAKSJD!!!!";

    int[] letters           = new int[123]; // Because from '0' to 'z', the highest is 122.

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c <= 122) letters[c] += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("LETTER COUNT:");
    for (int i = 'A'; i < 'Z'; ++i) {
        if ((letters[i] + letters[i + 32]) > 0) System.out.println((char)i + " -> " + (letters[i] + letters[i + 32]));
    }

    System.out.println("NUMBER COUNT:");
    for (int i = '0'; i < '9'; ++i) {
        System.out.println((char)i + " -> " + letters[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap might not be the cheapest solution but if someone don't cares much about it, it is at least possible with only one loop and it is straight forward. Hope this helpse someone.

```
    public static void charOccurence(String string) {
        // create a char array out of your string
        char[] chs = string.toCharArray();
        // create a map for storing your character and count pairs
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();      
        // loop trough using the string length
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length() ; i++) {
            // if you already have the letter stored simply add one to the count
            if (map.containsKey(chs[i])) {
                int count = map.get(chs[i]) + 1;
                map.put(chs[i], count);
            // else add your letter for the first time with the count of 1
            } else {
                map.put(chs[i], 1);
            }
        }
        // print results
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A HashMap would probably be the easiest implementation for this problem in Java.

```
public static String charCounter(String str) {
    // Initialize counter HashMap with 0 value counts for desired characters
    HashMap<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    String indexes = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i=0; i<indexes.length;i++){
        counter.put(indexes.charAt(i), 0);
    }

    // Update HashMap by incrementing for each character in the string
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char charAt = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i));
        int count = counter.containsKey(charAt) ? counter.get(charAt) : 0;
        counter.put(charAt, count+1)
    }

    // Print out the counts
    for (int i=0; i<indexes.length; i++) {
        char index = Character.toUpperCase(indexes.charAt(i));
        int count = counter.get(index);
        if (counter.get(index) >= 0)
            System.out.println(index + " = " + count);
    }
    return str;

}
```

Comment: No. A `HashMap` is far less efficient than the array the OP is using. I recommend finding a blog post or something to that effect about how HashMaps work under the hood and how arrays work in Java to see why. You gain very little by using a `HashMap` in the OPs use case.

Comment: Fair enough. Changed to "easiest implementation" A HashMap would perhaps be a bit slower than an array, however, the algorithm is still O(n) in terms of the string size, and there was no indication that OP

Comment: This is still a down-vote for me, unfortunately. The OPs question is about efficiency, and this is less efficient than what the OP has already done.

Comment: Pretty sure OP's main concern was correctness rather than efficiency since he couldn't get 0 counts to show up, but alright.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I will undownvote as this seems to address the question and is not incorrect (although I've only skimmed and not personally verified - it just looks correct at first glance)